# Get differential equation of derivative

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, differential-equations, differentiation

I have a differential equation that looks like this:

```
dT/dx = (1+alpha\*M1)\*(T^2)\*S(x) - 4\*(2+gamma\*M2)\*x\*T
```

I want to differentiate this equation let's say over `alpha`. However, `T` depends on `alpha`. How can I get a differential equation that *includes* the derivative `dT/da` so I can solve for it (using `ode45` or something)?

**Note:** I can't differentiate the equation by hand as I will need to do this for the `Ys` as well, where I don't have an easy analytical function.

My code so far:

```
syms L alpha gamma Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 x T X

M1 = 0;
M2 = 7;
Y1 = 1 + M2 / 10;
Y7 = 3 + M1 / 10;
xcp = [0 0.1*L 0.25*L 0.5*L 0.6*L 0.75*L L];
ycp = [Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7];
T0 = 5 + 1/L - 25/(L^2);
S = bezier_syms(); % Assume this returns a function of L,x,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6

ode = diff(T,x) == (1+alphaM1)*(T^2)*S(L,x,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6) - 4*(2 + gamma*M2)xT;
```

Comment: You’ll have to define T as a function of alpha. I think it’s something like `syms T(alpha)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That's a start but that doesn't get me far. Neither ode45 nor dsolve seem to like it

Answer (score 0):

Given the equation

```
dT/dx = F(x,T,a)
```

and `U=dT/da`, then by the rules of differentiation like the chain rule, you get

```
dU/dx = dF/da(x,T,a) + dF/dT(x,T,a)*U
```

where the partial derivatives are easy to determine. For more precise formulas, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3699281/115115